Where would I debate a character?
This isn't really a question for this site specifically. Does anyone know where I would be able to post an analysis of a character from a piece of pre-existing fiction on Stack Exchange? Specifically, what community on here would be the best place for that?
If I wanted to give my opinion on a character and ask for other people's opinions, where on Stack Exchange would I do that?

The Stack Exchange system is not adequate for the discussion of anything. It is a collection of Question & Answer sites.
A better place for discussions are social media or a forum, especially one dedicated to your specific genre. Reddit, for example, has "subreddits" for almost every topic imaginable.
